# Multipart request with file and JSON object

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, postman

I trying to create function that will get Multipart file and json as input parameters. I write such function, here is it:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<UserWithPhoto> update(@RequestHeader(value="Access-key") String accessKey,
                                         @RequestHeader(value="Secret-key") String secretKey,
                                         @RequestPart("user") String string,
                                         @RequestPart("photo") MultipartFile file) throws Exception{
            User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(string, User.class);
```

But the problem is cant't test it. I use Postman client like this and get error `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided`
 I believe it because I don't set postman write [image]

Comment: You are missing Content-Type: multipart/related in Headers (but this might not be the only issue)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a MultipartResolver to your Spring MVC Config:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
```

Comment: yes it was there from the beginning. problem was that I passing body parameters as http get method, I changed it to post and it works now. Thanks